How to Retrieve the blocked messages like mms and sms in android kotlin programmatically?


cursor?.use {
            val uri = Uri.parse("content://mms")
            val projection = arrayOf("_id", "date", "msg_box", "thread_id")
            val selection: String? = null
            val selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null
            val sortOrder: String? = null

            application.applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
                uri,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder
            )
                ?.use { mmsCursor ->
                    while (mmsCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        val dateIndex = mmsCursor.getLong(mmsCursor.getColumnIndex("date"))
                        val epochTimeMilliseconds = dateIndex * 1000
                        val formattedMmsSeconds =
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + (epochTimeMilliseconds - System.currentTimeMillis())
                        val mmsId = mmsCursor.getString(mmsCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")).toInt()
                        val msgBox =
                            mmsCursor.getInt(mmsCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("msg_box"))
                        val utcDate = Date(dateIndex * 1000L) // convert to milliseconds
                        val date = utcDate.toAPIFormat()
                        val partUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/$mmsId/part")

                        application.applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
                            partUri,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null
                        )
                            ?.use { partCursor ->
                                while (partCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                    val partId =
                                        partCursor.getString(partCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))
                                    val type =
                                        partCursor.getString(partCursor.getColumnIndex("ct"))
                                    val phoneNumber = getSenderAndReceiverNumbers(mmsId)
                                    val myPhoneNumber = getPhoneNumber()
                                    val messageType: String = getMessageType(msgBox)
                                    val contactName = getContactNameFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                                    deviceNumber = myPhoneNumber.replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "")
                                    val imageUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/part/$partId")
                                    val imagePath = getImagePath(imageUri)
                                    if (type != null && type.contains("image") && imagePath != null) {

                                        viewModelScope.launch {
                                            val bitmap = partId?.let { getMmsImage(it) }
                                            val myIntList = getIdsFromSharedPreferences()

                                            if (shouldProcessMms(
                                                    myIntList,
                                                    partId,
                                                    formattedMmsSeconds,
                                                    lastDate
                                                ) && bitmap != null
                                            ) {
                                                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                                    val mmsImageUrl = saveImage(bitmap)
                                                    val message: String? =
                                                        getMmsText(mmsId.toString())
                                                    val messageText = when {
                                                        message.isNullOrEmpty() -> ""
                                                        result.any { it.mmsId == mmsId } -> ""
                                                        else -> message
                                                    }
                                                    val mmsMessage = MmsMessage(
                                                        0,
                                                        mmsId,
                                                        partId.toInt(),
                                                        myPhoneNumber.ifEmpty { noSimCard },
                                                        phoneNumber,
                                                        contactName.ifEmpty {
                                                            getContactName(messageType)
                                                        },
                                                        messageText,
                                                        date,
                                                        messageType,
                                                        mmsImageUrl.getRealPath(application.applicationContext),
                                                        false,
                                                        generateMessageId(),
                                                        BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME,
                                                        ""
                                                    )
                                                    result.add(mmsMessage)
                                                }
                                            }
                                            addJsonId(partId)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
        }



Note : we are using feature for sideloading purpose (testing) not for actual public use we are experimenting on this
Issue Description: for example i have an Android device where I have blocked my friend's contact number ,when my friend text i may not able see the messages because the system doesn't show to me, here i need to retrieve the messages like sms and mms  which was sent by my friend  in blocked state
SO far tried solutions  :

I have tried to use the AccessibilityService to detect any events are triggered while the blocked member is messaging.
Tried using broadcast receivers but i didn't receives any triggers on it

i am using the below mentioned code to get the messages
Expected output :  i need to detect when the blocked person message me
solutions and your suggestion are welcome thanks in advance !!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Retrieving SMS and MMS messages from a blocked contact on an Android device can be challenging because the default behavior of the Android operating system is to hide or discard these messages. However, there are a few approaches you can try to recover these messages, depending on your specific device and its configuration.

@BobSmith thanks for your reply , here i don't have a exact code which retrieve the blocked messages, i have searched on web still i couldn't find it that's why i posted with the detailed description of my issue , and i using both device one is Pixel 7a running android 15 beta and other one is Samsung galaxy s10 lite which is running on android 13

Welcome to stackoverflow! Read this post and edit your question. You have to put efforts before asking for help. Do some R&D and share it with us so that we can look into that or suggest you better approach to achieve it. This is how stackoverflow works.
